# A cache that can be indexed using multiple indexes

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, caching

I am looking for a way to create a class in C#, let's call it "Cache.cs" that will function essentially as an in-memory cache.

The most important aspect of this cache is to have the indexing be flexible. I would like to `REGISTER` different indexes (maybe dictionaries?) with the Cache (in some way) and when I add/remove an element to the cache the indexes registered would update. When I query the data from this cache I would provide an index that I registered with the cache and a key appropriate for that index.

Has anyone written something like this that they could share? any third-party libraries?

Comment: Using/implementing multiple indexes is very common programming task... but it does not make the question "share sources or link to a library" on-topic for SO.

Comment: A dictionary key is a hash.  Dictionaries don't have indexes but you can enumerate through the keys in order using AsEnumerable().

Comment: If your indexes are unique secondary keys derived from the value, you might port [IndexMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/IndexableCache.md). I had used lock striping for consistent updates of the multiple maps. I haven't needed anything like it in years, but shows the gist of how it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://cachemanager.michaco.net, which has an in-memory implementation.

Good luck!

Comment: This looks great but unfortunately this is basically a fancy 1-key dictionary.